# Example of commutative ring with two elements that don't generate entire ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

I believe that there should be an example of a commutative ring $R$ that contains two elements whose only
common divisors are units but which do not generate the unit ideal.

$R$ can't be a Euclidean domain. I've been trying out some basic examples of non-integral domains, such as $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, but without luck so far.

Is there such an example?

Comment: How about $\Bbb Z[X,Y]$?

Comment: You won't be able to make this work if all ideals are principal.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Comment to solution, please?